# Wordpress plugin header already sent

Tags: plugins

I bulid contact form, wich redirects after submit to success page. but some how i get error

```
 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\w\wp-includes\post-template.php:1178) in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\w\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1173
```

I resolve this problem by adding ob_start at pluggable file, but it s not option because plugin should be used on diffrent sites. This is my file

```
  <?php
include_once("lib/smer_collection.php");
include_once( "lib/drzava_collection.php");
include_once('konstante.php');

if ($_GET["ajax"]) {
    $id_drzava = $_POST["id_drzava"];
    //print_r( $id_drzava);
    $selektovanaDrzava = DrzavaCollection::GetSelectedDrzava($id_drzava);

    foreach ($selektovanaDrzava as $selectedItem) {
        echo $selectedItem->GetPhoneCode(); //." ".$selectedItem->GetSrpskiNaziv() ;
    }
    exit;
}

/**
 * Pozivamo skriptu pre teksta 604 da bi se akcija izvrsila na ovoj stranici prijava.php
 */
include ('skriptaPre604.php');
// prilagodjavamo regexp JS-u
$validate['txtEmail'] = array('options' => array('regexp' => "/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/"));
$validate['txtPtt'] = array('options' => array('regexp' => '/^[0-9]+$/'));
$validate['txtPozivniBroj'] = array('options' => array('regexp' => '/^\d{2,3}$/'));
$validate['txtTelefon'] = array('options' => array('regexp' => '/^\d{5,16}$/'));

?>

        <style>
            .dataInfo {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .pozicija{float:right;
                      clear: both;
                      right: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function JeBroj(strString)
                    //check for valid numeric strings   
                    {
                        var strValidChars = "0123456789";
                        var strChar;
                        var blnResult = true;
                        if (strString.length == 0)
                            return false;
                        //test strString consists of valid characters listed above
                        for (i = 0; i < strString.length && blnResult == true; i++)
                        {
                            strChar = strString.charAt(i);
                            if (strValidChars.indexOf(strChar) == -1)
                            {
                                blnResult = false;
                            }
                        }
                        return blnResult;
                    }



            function errorBox(me, text) {
                var span = document.createElement("LABEL");
                t = document.createTextNode(text);
                span.appendChild(t);
                span.style.color = "red";
                span.setAttribute('for', me.getAttribute("id"));
                span.setAttribute('class', 'pozicija');
                span.setAttribute("id", me.getAttribute("id") + "_error");
                me.parentNode.insertBefore(span, me);
                me.style.border = "2px solid red";
            }

            $('document').ready(function() {
<?php
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

    if ($value === false)
        echo "errorBox(document.getElementById('$key'),'$greske[$key]');\n";
}
?>
            });
            function proveriPolje(mene, filter, text, def) {

                if (document.getElementById(mene.getAttribute("id") + "_error") != null) {
                    document.getElementById(mene.getAttribute("id") + "_error").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(mene.getAttribute("id") + "_error"));
                    mene.style.border = "1px solid blue";
                }
                ukloniCaption(mene, def);

                var x = mene.value;
                if (!filter.test(x)) {
                    errorBox(mene, text);
                    return false;
                }


                if (def !== undefined)
                    postaviCaption(mene, def);
            }
            function proveriUnose()
            {
                var ok = true;
<?php
foreach ($greske as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($validate[$key]['options']['regexp']))
        $regIzraz = $validate[$key]['options']['regexp'];
    else
        $regIzraz = "/[\s\S]/";


    echo "if(proveriPolje(document.getElementById('$key'), $regIzraz, '$greske[$key]', '$def[$key]') == false) ok = false; \n";
}
?>             
                return ok;




            }
            function proveriNacinSkolovanja() {
                smerIT = document.getElementById("radInfo4");
                //smerEP = document.getElementById("radInfo5");
                if (smerIT.checked) {
                    document.getElementById("radioNacin2").checked = true;
                    document.getElementById("radioNacin1").disabled = true;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("radioNacin1").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("radioNacin1").checked = true;
                }
            }
            function prikaziPolja()
            {
                document.getElementById('Maticni').style.display = '';
                /*      document.getElementById('textUsmerenje').innerHTML = 'Želim da upišem:';*/
                document.getElementById('NacinPlacanjaR').style.display = '';
                document.getElementById('NacinPlacanjaT').style.display = '';
                document.getElementById('PitanjeT').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('PitanjeR').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('Popust').style.display = '';
                if (document.getElementById('radioNacin1').checked)
                {
                    document.getElementById('ProgramPlus').style.display = '';
                    document.getElementById('ProgramPlusText').style.display = '';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('ProgramPlus').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('ProgramPlusText').style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
            function proveriDrzavu()
            {
                //alert('-'+document.getElementById('cmbDrzava').value+'-');
                //if (document.getElementById('cmbDrzava').value=="SRB - Srbija"){
                //document.getElementById('pttTR').style.display = '';
                //document.getElementById('lkTR').style.display = '';
                //} else {
                //document.getElementById('pttTR').style.display = 'none';
                //document.getElementById('lkTR').style.display = 'none';
                //}
            }
            function proveriSmer()
            {
                cmb = document.getElementById('cmbSmer');
            }
            function ukloniCaption(input, txt) {
                if (input.value == txt) {
                    input.value = '';
                    input.style.color = '#000000';
                }
            }
            function postaviCaption(input, txt) {
                if (input.value == '') {
                    input.value = txt;
                    input.style.color = '#799492';
                }
            }
        </script>    



                        <?php if (strlen($greska) > 0) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="Text" style="margin-top:5px; margin-right:20px; color: red;">  <b>Poštovani,</b>
                                <br>
                                    podaci koje ste uneli nisu validni, probajte ponovo
                                    <br/>
                                    <?php // echo $greska;   ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>


                        <form class="prijava2" name="myform" id="myform" method="post" action="#">
                            <div class="plavaforma">
                                <p class="labela standard11">Izaberite program:</p>
                                <?php
                                $smerovi = SmerCollection::Get();
//print_r($smerovi);
                                $redni_broj = 1;
                                foreach ($smerovi as $item) {
                                    ?>
                                    <input type="radio" name="radInfo" id="radInfo<?php echo $redni_broj ?>" <?php if ($redni_broj == 1) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>value="<?php echo $item->GetUID(); ?>" onclick="proveriNacinSkolovanja()"/>
                                    <label for="radInfo<?php echo $redni_broj; ?>" class="naslov"><?php echo $item->GetNaziv(); ?></label>&nbsp;<label for="radInfo<?php echo $redni_broj; ?>" class="najmanjiTekst">(<?php echo $item->GetOpis(); ?>)</label><br/>
                                    <?php
                                    ++$redni_broj;
                                }
                                ?>              
                                <p class="labela standard11">Recite nam Vaše osnovne podatke:</p>
                                <table class="dataInfo">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="vertical-align:top">Zovem se <br/></td>
                                        <td style="  width: 80%; ">
                                            <input name="txtIme" <?= isset($data["txtIme"]) ? "value='{$data["txtIme"]}'" : "" ?> type="text"  id="txtIme" value="Ime" class="caption" onfocus="ukloniCaption(this, 'Ime')" onblur="<?= "proveriPolje(this, {$validate['txtIme']['options']['regexp']}, '{$greske['txtIme']}', '{$def['txtIme']}')"; ?>"/>

                                            <input name="txtPrezime" <?= isset($data["txtPrezime"]) ? "value='{$data["txtPrezime"]}'" : "" ?>type="text"  id="txtPrezime" value="Prezime" class="caption" onfocus="ukloniCaption(this, 'Prezime')" onblur="<?= "proveriPolje(this, {$validate['txtPrezime']['options']['regexp']}, '{$greske['txtPrezime']}', '{$def['txtPrezime']}')"; ?>"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="vertical-align:top">Moja adresa je</td>
                                        <td><input name="txtUlica" <?= isset($data["txtUlica"]) ? "value='{$data["txtUlica"]}'" : "" ?> type="text" id="txtUlica" size="28" onblur="<?= "proveriPolje(this, {$validate['txtUlica']['options']['regexp']}, '{$greske['txtUlica']}', '{$def['txtUlica']}')"; ?>" />
                                            <label>Broj:</label>
                                            <input type="text" <?= isset($data["BrojUlice"]) ? "value='{$data["BrojUlice"]}'" : "" ?> name="BrojUlice" id="BrojUlice" value="" size="5" onblur="<?= "proveriPolje(this, {$validate['BrojUlice']['options']['regexp']}, '{$greske['BrojUlice']}', '{$def['BrojUlice']}')"; ?>"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Grad</td>
                                        <td><input name="txtGrad" <?= isset($data["txtGrad"]) ? "value='{$data["txtGrad"]}'" : "" ?> type="text" id="txtGrad" size="45" onblur="<?= "proveriPolje(this, {$validate['txtGrad']['options']['regexp']}, '{$greske['txtGrad']}', '{$def['txtGrad']}')"; ?>" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr id="pttTR">
                                        <td>Poštanski broj</td>
                                        <td><input name="txtPtt" <?= isset($data["txtPtt"]) ? "value='{$data["txtPtt"]}'" : "" ?> type="text" id="txtPtt" size="45" onblur="<?= "proveriPolje(this, {$validate['txtPtt']['options']['regexp']}, '{$greske['txtPtt']}', '{$def['txtPtt']}')"; ?>" /></td>
                                    </tr>                           
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Država</td>                         
                                        <td>
                                            <select name="cmbDrzava" id="cmbDrzava" onchange="proveriDrzavu();">

                                                <?php
                                                $drzave = DrzavaCollection::GetDrzavaList();
                                                foreach ($drzave as $item) {
                                                    ?>

                                                    <option value="<?php echo $item->GetCountryCode() ?>" <?php if ($item->GetId() == IDDRZAVASRBIJA) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $item->GetSrpskiNaziv(); ?></option>
                                                    <?php
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                            </select>   
                                            <script>
                                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                                    $("#cmbDrzava").change(function() {
                                                        val = $("#cmbDrzava :selected").val();

                                                        $.ajax({
                                                            type: "POST",
                                                            url: "<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);?>prijava.php?ajax=1",
                                                            data: "id_drzava=" + val,
                                                            success: function(msg) {
                                                                $("[name='txtPozivniDrzave']").val(msg);
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    });
                                                });</script>   
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Moj telefon je</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select style="width:155px" name="txtPozivniDrzave">
                                                <?php
                                                $drzave = DrzavaCollection::GetPhoneCodeList();
                                                foreach ($drzave as $item) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $item->GetPhoneCode() ?>" <?php if ($item->GetId() == IDDRZAVASRBIJA) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo$item->GetPhoneCode() . " " . $item->GetSrpskiNaziv(); ?></option>
                                                    <?php
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                            </select>
                                            <input name="txtPozivniBroj" <?= isset($data["txtPozivniBroj"]) ? "value='{$data["txtPozivniBroj"]}'" : "" ?> type="text" id="txtPozivniBroj" size="3" onblur="<?= "proveriPolje(this, {$validate['txtPozivniBroj']['options']['regexp']}, '{$greske['txtPozivniBroj']}', '{$def['txtPozivniBroj']}')"; ?>" maxlength="3"/>
                                            <input name="txtTelefon" <?= isset($data["txtTelefon"]) ? "value='{$data["txtTelefon"]}'" : "" ?> type="text" id="txtTelefon" size="9" onblur="<?= "proveriPolje(this, {$validate['txtTelefon']['options']['regexp']}, '{$greske['txtTelefon']}', '{$def['txtTelefon']}')"; ?>"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Moja e-pošta</td>
                                        <td><input name="txtEmail" <?= isset($data["txtEmail"]) ? "value='{$data["txtEmail"]}'" : "" ?> type="text" id="txtEmail" size="45" onblur="<?= "proveriPolje(this, {$validate['txtEmail']['options']['regexp']}, '{$greske['txtEmail']}', '{$def['txtEmail']}')"; ?>"/></td>
                                    </tr>   
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Moj JMBG</td>
                                        <td><input name="txtMaticni" <?= isset($data["txtMaticni"]) ? "value='{$data["txtMaticni"]}'" : "" ?> type="text" id="txtMaticni" size="45" onblur="<?= "proveriPolje(this, {$validate['txtMaticni']['options']['regexp']}, '{$greske['txtMaticni']}', '{$def['txtMaticni']}')"; ?>"/></td>
                                    </tr>                                                                                                                                           
                                </table>
                                <p class="labela standard11">Izaberite način školovanja:</p>
                                <input name="radioNacin" id="radioNacin1" type="radio" value="<?php echo UID_STUDENT_VRSTA_TRADICIONALNO; ?>" checked="checked" />
                                <label for="radioNacin1">Tradicionalno (fizičkim prisustvom na predavanjima)</label><br/>

                                <input name="radioNacin" id="radioNacin2" type="radio" value="<?php echo UID_STUDENT_VRSTA_ONLINE; ?>" />
                                <label for="radioNacin2">Na daljinu (on-line, preko obezbeđene distance learning platforme)</label>             
                                <p class="labela standard11">Izaberite način plaćanja:</p>
                                <input name="radioNacinPlacanja" id="radioOdjednom" type="radio" value="<?php echo PLACANJE_ODJEDNOM; ?>" checked="checked" />
                                <label for="radioOdjednom">Odjednom (sa popustom od 10%)</label><br/>
                                <input name="radioNacinPlacanja" id="radioRate" type="radio" value="<?php echo PLACANJE_RATE; ?>" />
                                <label for="radioRate">12 rata</label><br/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="<?= INTERSPIRE_HIDDEN_POLJE ?>" value="250">
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="submit" name="subPosalji" id="subPosalji" value="Prijavi se! " class="dugmePrijava2" onclick="return proveriUnose();" />                                                                                                                  
                                        </form>
                                        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

And included script wich validate form and redirect

```
<?php
include_once('lib/class.phpmailer.php');
include_once('lib/class.smtp.php');
include_once ("lib/smer.php");
include_once ("lib/student_vrsta.php");
include_once ( "lib/funkcije.php");
include_once ("konstante.php");

global $wpdb;


       (string) $ime = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($data['txtIme']));
       (string) $prezime =htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($data['txtPrezime']));
       (string) $email =htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($data['txtEmail']));
       (int) $jmbg =htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($data['txtMaticni']));
       (string) $telefon = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($data['txtTelefon']));
       (string) $adresa = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($data['txtUlica']));
       (int) $broj =htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($data['BrojUlice']));
       (int) $ptt = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($data['txtPtt']));
       (string) $grad =htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($data['txtGrad']));
       (string) $drzava = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($data['cmbDrzava']));
       (string) $placanje = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($data['radioNacinPlacanja']));
       (string) $skolovanje = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($data['radioNacin']));
       (string) $odsek =htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($data['Odsek']));
       (string) $vreme =htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($vremeTZ));

    //  var_dump($data);
        $query =$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_prijavljeniupis(UID,Ime,Prezime,email,JMBG,Telefon, Adresa,BrojUlice,PttBroj,Grad,Drzava,NacinPlacanja,NacinSkolovanja,Odsek,DatumPrijave) VALUES (UUID(),'{$ime}','{$prezime}','{$email}','{$jmbg}','{$telefon}','{$adresa}','{$broj}','{$ptt}','{$grad}','{$drzava}','{$placanje}','{$skolovanje}','{$odsek}',$vremeTZ)");
        $last_inserted_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
         if ($query == FALSE){
            //nije uspeo upis, hajde ponovo
            $location = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

               wp_redirect($location);
                exit();

        }
        $UID_query = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT `UID` FROM `wp_prijavljeniupis` WHERE `id`='{$last_inserted_id}' ");
        $query = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_prijavljena_lica (UID,Ime,Prezime,email,DatumPrijave) VALUES ('{$UID_query->UID}','{$ime}','{$prezime}','{$email}',$vremeTZ)");


        $txtBody = "Poštovani, <br/><br/>Moje ime:    {$ime} {$prezime} <br/>
                    E-mail adresa:     {$email} <br/>
                    Maticni broj (JMBG):    {$jmbg} <br/>
                    Kontakt telefon:     {$telefon} <br/>
                    Ulica i broj:    {$ulica} {$broj} <br/>
                    Postanski broj:  {$ptt} <br/>
                    Grad:    {$grad} <br/>
                    Zemlja:  {$drzava} <br/>
                    Broj licne karte:    {$data["txtBRLK"]} <br/>
                    Izabrani odsek:    " . $odsek . " <br/>                             
                    Nacin skolovanja:    {$skolovanje} <br/>
                    Nacin placanja:  {$placanje} <br/>
                    ";

      //  $posetilacInfoMailBody = $posetilac->posaljiMailPosetilacInfo('Prijavljen za Upis', true);
       // $txtBody .= $posetilacInfoMailBody;
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
        $mail->From = CMS_EMAIL_OFFICE;
        $mail->FromName = CMS_COMPANY_NAME;
        $mail->Subject = "Prijava za upis";
        $mail->IsMail();
        $mail->MsgHTML($txtBody);
        $mail->AddAddress('office@it-akademija.com');
        //$mail->AddBCC(CMS_EMAIL_TESTING);

//exit();

        if (!$mail->Send()) {
            foreach ($mail->ErrorInfo as $errMsg) {
                $greska .= $errMsg;
            }
            @error_log("[" . date("d.m.Y H:i", time()) . "]\t(" . __FILE__ . " - line: " . __LINE__ . ")\t" . " mail nije poslat: " . $greska . "\t IDKorisnik: " . $idPrKor . "\n", 3, SERVER_ROOT . "/cms/mestoZaUploadFajlove/error_mail.log");
        }
       // include("curl_http_client.php");
       // $curl = &new Curl_HTTP_Client();

        //pretend to be IE6 on windows
       // $useragent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
        //$curl->set_user_agent($useragent);

        //Subscribe to form 12
        //$post_data = array('email' => $email, 'CustomFields[1]' => $ime, 'CustomFields[2]' => $prezime, 'format' => 'h', INTERSPIRE_HIDDEN_POLJE => $_REQUEST[INTERSPIRE_HIDDEN_POLJE]);
       // $html_data = $curl->send_post_data(INTERSPIRE_ADDRESS . "form.php?form=12", $post_data);

        //Unsubscribe form 14
      //  $post_data = array('email' => $data['txtEmail']);
       //$html_data = $curl->send_post_data(INTERSPIRE_ADDRESS . "unsubform.php?form=14", $post_data);
        //echo $html_data;

        $page_id = get_option('page_id');
        $location = get_permalink(get_page($page_id));
       //$location = home_url().'/potvrda-prijave/';
        wp_safe_redirect($location);
```

Can someone help me how to solve this problem, changing files outside plugin its not option

Comment: Sorry, but no one will review your complete code to search for syntax errors - especially when your tables, variables, etc. are named with non English names that maybe 1% of the readers will understand. Please narrow down your problem or build a test case and [edit] your question.

Comment: its not about errors, i just show structure of code, i will find soultion, just show me the way

Comment: This usually just is a syntax error. And on top of that you are doing everything in a non-WP way. Starting with short PHP tags (not available on every server and deprecated for current PHP versions) to accessing the DB not via the WPDB object, etc. etc.